# Excel, ActiveCell.Row depends on clicking vs. pressing enter

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code in a worksheet that is a worksheet change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change
```

On this worksheet, I have dropdowns with data validation. So I can select a dropdown and choose "Fruit." After making my selection, the worksheet change event takes note of what row I'm currently in and does additional stuff with that information.

However, if I instead type "Fruit" and press Enter, the cursor/selector goes down a row, and the worksheet change event now targets the wrong row.

Is there a way around this? Can I have it detect if the worksheet change event was done with a click versus an Enter-press?

Or is there a way to prevent someone from just typing anything and force them to click instead?

Or is there something better to use than ActiveCell.Row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to rely on ActiveCell when using `Worksheet_Change`. When the event is fired, you also have the parameter `Target` of type `Range` available, this gives you the exact range that has changed, either by data validation selector or by manually editing cell and pressing Enter.

The code looks like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```